# I'm having an issue with Greek letters in Jupyter Markdown. Ideas on a fix?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am doing some work in Jupyter Notebook which necessitates Greek letters. (\mu, \sigma, etc.).  In code cells the \mu followed by TAB works fine.  In a markdown cell I expect either the lower or uppercase Greek letter, but when I hit TAB, the entire string of text shifts to the right as in a typical word processor.  This is new behavior.  I'd like to fix this.

```
print('α psyho disco β') - #This works in a code cell. 

\alpha psycho disco \beta -#This doesn't work in a markdown cell
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In a markdown cell the Greek letters should be surrounded with the dollar sign:

```
$\alpha$ psycho disco $\beta$
```

You may use a double dollar sign at the beginning and the end of the Greek letter (or math equation) in order to display it inline.

```
Following is the 'beta' letter: $$\beta$$
```